# how to take an iterable object as a function parameter? (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript

example:

```
function foo(iterable) {
    for (let i of iterable) {}
}
```

What type could iterable be here asides from any?
other examples include Array.from and most of the other iterable data structure constructors.

Comment: type : `Array<String>`

Comment: I mean all the array can be iterable, is that the question what should type of iterable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterable is an ES6 feature, so setting your tsc target to "es6" lets you take in an Iterable as a parameter, e.g.

```
function foo<T>(iterable: Iterable<T>) {
    for (let i of iterable) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell typescript the type of your parameter, so it could compile:

```
function foo(iterable:Array<any>) {
    for (let i of iterable) {}
}
```

[Types could iterate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html)